# Adding multiple arraylist integers together

Tags: java, arraylist

---

UPDATED:

After making the changes using Mike Kobit's answer, i wanted to move the files that i have already calculated to a different folder. the files do not successfully move and i dont know why? Does it have to do with the array list locking the files?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    fSplit(path);   

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS");
    String d_f = d.format(date);

    System.out.println(allSums);

    try {
        File fold = new File(path);
        for(File k : fold.listFiles()) {
            System.out.println(k.getName());
            if(k.getName().contains("file")) { //named files read to be moved
                boolean success = k.renameTo(new File(path2 + "\\" + k.getName()));
                if(!success) {
                    System.out.println("FAILED MOVE");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

private static void fSplit(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //ArrayList<Integer> allSums = new ArrayList<>();
    //ArrayList<List<Integer>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();

    File folder = new File(path);

    for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
        //System.out.println(f.getName());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + "\\" + f.getName()));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(br);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        // Store each read list into a container for all of the lists
        allLists.add(list);

        //System.out.println(list);
    }

    // Assuming all lists are the same size
    //int listLength = allLists.get(0).size();

    // Iterate over each index
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        // For each index, add the elements from that index in each list
        for(List<Integer> list : allLists) {
            sum += list.get(i);
        }
        // Add the current indexes sum to the final list
        allSums.add(sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: read this http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-can-finally-join-strings

Comment: @KickButtowski That seems to be about concatenating strings, not summing integers.

Comment: @Takendarkk I thought the op wants to have all the elements in an array :)

Comment: He wants a new array where each element is the sum of all the ints at that position in the other arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of your arrays and then you can iterate over them. Here is your example with added comments and how you could sum up the elements after.

```
ArrayList<Integer> allSums = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<List<Integer>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();
for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + "\\" + f.getName()));
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(br);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    // Store each read list into a container for all of the lists
    allLists.add(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

// Assuming all lists are the same size
final int listLength = allLists.get(0).size();
// Iterate over each index
for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    // For each index, add the element from that index in each list
    for (List<Integer> list : allLists) {
        sum += list.get(i);
    }
    // Add the current indexes sum to the final list
    allSums.add(sum);
}
// allSums contains the sum from every index

// Using Java 8 streams
allSums.clear();
IntStream.range(0, listLength)
        .forEach((i) -> allSums.add(i, allLists.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt((c) -> c.get(i)))));
System.out.println(allSums);
```

Output from both ways:
    [11, 12, 6, 5, 11]
    [11, 12, 6, 5, 11]

Comment: thank you. this answer was very clear for me using arbitrary numbers and comments for understanding

Comment: updated for more assistance. does reading files and storing in an array lock the files from being accessed to move to another directory?

Comment: I think that would be best addressed by asking another question on here.

Answer (score 0):

**Explantion**:In the for loop you will add all same index elements in different array with each other and save it in same index at result array

**Note**:

**my code is done with array but I am sure you can change it to arraylist very easily**

**Code**:

```
   List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3, 1, 0);
   List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 2, 1, 5);
   List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 1, 3, 6);

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // you cannot use reslut size because result does not have anything in it, so 
    // there is no size for result list.
    // you can use size each list as long as the size of all the list is the same

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        result.add(i, list1.get(i) + list2.get(i) + list3.get(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result.get(i)+" ");
    }
```

**Output**:

```
11 12 6 5 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add using ArrayList you can do this

```
    List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++) {
        sum.add(i, list1.get(i) + list2.get(i) + list3.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: there will be many files inside folder, (3) is just an example. in that case i will also need forloop for all list?

Comment: @userdp when you use arraylist there is no need to specified length cuz arraylist shrinks and expands by itself

Comment: yes you will need a nested for loop to iterate over each list